# ghc-mod does not use my cabal sandbox. why?

Tags: haskell, ghc-mod

```
runghc -package-db=.cabal-sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d hellowai.hs
```

Works perfect for me.

Similarly, with

```
ghci -package-db=.cabal-sandbox/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d
```

I am also able to import my cabal-sandbox-installed `Wai` package in `ghci` with no issue at all.

But when I ask `ghc-mod` to validate my haskell source code, via

```
ghc-mod check --boundary="" -g -package-db=.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.8.3-packages.conf.d hellowai.hs
hellowai.hs:4:8:Could not find module ‘Network.Wai.Handler.Warp’Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
hellowai.hs:3:8:Could not find module ‘Network.HTTP.Types’Perhaps you meant  Network.HTTP.Base (from HTTP-4000.2.19)  Network.HTTP.Base (needs flag -package HTTP-4000.2.10)  Network.HTTP.Headers (needs flag -package HTTP-4000.2.10)Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
hellowai.hs:2:8:Could not find module ‘Network.Wai’Perhaps you meant  Network.BSD (needs flag -package network-2.4.2.3)  Network.URI (needs flag -package network-2.4.2.3)  Network.TCP (needs flag -package HTTP-4000.2.10)Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

It is unable to find my cabal sandbox installed module.  Why is that so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a `cabal.sandbox.config` file? And are you using a `.cabal` file for your project?

If you have both of these you should be able to use `ghc-mod check ...` and it will just work.

Another advantage of using a .cabal file is that you can use `cabal repl` to invoke ghci and `cabal run` to invoke `runhaskell` with the correct command line options.

*Update*

Here is a recipe you can try out to see when ghc-mod can find your cabal sandbox. Perhaps this can help you determine what's different with your set up.

Start in a clean directory:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cabal get split
$ cd split-0.2.2
$ cabal sandbox init --sandbox=../.cabal-sandbox
```

Edit around line 55 of split.cabal to add `heredoc` as a dependency.

Edit src/Data/List/Split.hs to use the module `Text.Heredoc`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes #-}
...
import Text.Heredoc
...
foo :: String
foo = [here|this is a test|]
```

Make sure `heredoc` is installed:

```
$ cabal install --only-dependencies
```

Finally this should work:

```
$ ghc-mod check ./src/Data/List/Split.hs
```

And it will still work if you cd into a sub-directory:

```
$ cd src
$ ghc-mod check ./Data/List/Split.hs
```

However, ghc-mod won't work if you move away `split.cabal`:

```
(back at the top level directory)
$ mv split.cabal split.cabal-old
$ ghc-mod check ./src/Data/List/Split.hs
```

In this case I created the sandbox in a parent directory of our working directory, but things should also work if the initial sandbox was created like this:

```
$ mkdir foo
$ cd foo
$ mkdir sandbox-dir
$ cd sandbox-dir
$ cabal sandbox init
$ cd ..
$ cabal get split
$ cd split-0.2.2
$ cabal sandbox init --sandbox=../sandbox-dir/.cabal-sandbox
```

Comment: Absolutely. I have `cabal.sandbox.config` file present in the directory where I am running my `ghc-mod check` commands. But `ghc-mod` still does not know to check for available packages in my sandbox.

Comment: My experimentation shows that you also need a .cabal file.

Comment: How can I generate a `.cabal` file?

Comment: And no, even with my `.cabal` file, `ghc-mod` still does not know where to look for my 3rd party packages in the cabal sandbox.

Comment: Nope. Both `cabal repl` and `cabal run` cannot find the sandbox either... :-(

Comment: But `cabal exec -- runghc hellowai.hs` works (i.e. able to find the sandbox)

Comment: You can always create a symlink for cabal.sandbox.config that points to the real file.

Comment: I am not sure I understood what you meant.  My project source file `hellowai.hs` is in the same directory as my `cabal.sandbox.conf` file.

Comment: You can also use `cabal sandbox init --path=...` to create a cabal.sandbox.config file which points to an existing .cabal-sandbox directory.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a recipe which works for me. Perhaps you can use it to figure out what is different with your setup.

Comment: Added an example of where the sandbox dir is _not_ directly above the current working directory and how to configure the cabal.sandbox.config file to point to it.

Comment: `cabal` version `1.18.1.4`, `ghc-mod` version `5.2.1.2 compiled by GHC 7.8.3` with a valid project `.cabal` file containing the correct dependencies in `build-depends` solved the problem for me. Thank you for sharing your example!